# android.support.v7.widget.PopUpMenu seems to be missing

Tags: android, android-support-library

I added in the appcompat folder to my project.

I can't seem to however access the compatible v7 PopUpMenu widget (android.support.v7.widget.PopUpMenu)?

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

I used this to set it up. I may be missing something, but there doesn't seem to be a library with widgets under  /extras/android/support/v7 directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PopupMenu` class is in the **appcompat** library, the one that includes the compatible Action Bar. The class is inside the jar named `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`.